# Clear a timer in another API set by setInterval() created in one API

Tags: node.js, express, setinterval, clearinterval

Clear a timer in another API set by `setInterval()` created in one API.
I have an api which starts `setInterval()` and i save its timer-id in database.
When another API is called i want to clear old timer using old timer's timer-id from database. I know `clearInterval()` will do the job.

`clearInterval()` will do the job but, after saving it to DB`(JSON.stringify(intervalId))` and retrieve`(JSON.parse(intervalId))` it to kill timer, it's not working. Can't i get hold of timer once getting out of a function? Even if i save it in DB(timer-id). Am i doing anything wrong?

```
var intervalID = setInterval(function() {
console.log(intervalID);
/// Updating in DB
Model.updateById(Id, {timer_data: JSON.stringify(intervalID)});
}, 30000);
}
```

//Now retrieving and killing it

```
Model.findById(id).then(data=> {

var intervalID = JSON.parse(data.timer_data);
clearInterval(intervalID);

}
```

I expected old timer to be killed, but it still lives and executes. It removes all my assignments, i need it to be killed when required.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the browsers, `node.js` implementation of [`clearInterval()`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args) does not return a number ID. It returns a [`Timeout`](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_class_timeout) object. And because the object has Symbols, you would not be able to save it to a database.

As a workaround, I suggest to save the `Timeout` object in memory itself.

Here is a code snippet to help you out:

```
// Declaring the object
const inMemoryTimers = {};

/** Setting the timer */
// While saving the timer, saving the timer as inMemoryTimers[Id]
const timer = setInterval(() => {
    inMemoryTimers[Id] = timer;
}, 1000);

/** Clearing the timer */
// Retrieve the timer from inMemoryTimers
const timer = inMemoryTimers[Id];
clearInterval(timer);
```

Comment: it's not working for two different API's. One API initializes timer another tries to kill it. So when second API is called "const inMemoryTimers = {};" is again set to empty array, hence destroying old timer doesn't work. Can you suggest any saving in memory method which is available at project level. Thank you.

Comment: Are those two APIs in the same file ?

Comment: its a helper method, and yes both API's are in same file. I even tried to save timer data into cache. Even it is also not working, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: Then you can just define `const inMemoryTimers = {}` in the file context and not inside the helper function. That way, the object will be shared and will not be overwritten

Answer (score 0):

lets say we have 2 API
FirstAPI- have setinterval to repeat some code
SecondAPI- to clearInterval to stop repeat code

FirstAPI:

```
let intervalId = setIterval{
  if database have value == false ? continue code
  else clearInterval(intervalId)
}
```

SecondAPI:
is to set Database value to false

### The idea is generally :

is to `clearInterval` inside `setInterval` ,,, with true & false Flag in Database